# Query about CSS text animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I cannot figure out how to add a static word after this CSS text animation. Can someone please explain how to add a static word after this text animation? I would like to add the word 'Teams' after the animation. when I try to add the word it overlaps with the spans because it was positioned absolute.
I couldn't figure out how to do it.

```
<text-block class="sentence">For Modern
    <div class="verticalFlip">
        <span>Engineering</span> 
        <span>Manufacturing</span> 
        <span>Quality</span> 
        <span>Service</span> 
    </div>
<text-block/>
      
<Style>
    .sentence {
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    .verticalFlip {
        display: inline;
        text-indent: 3px;
    }

    .verticalFlip span {
        animation: vertical 10s linear infinite 0s;
        -ms-animation: vertical 10s linear infinite 0s;
        -webkit-animation: vertical 10s linear infinite 0s;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        height : 40px
    }
    .verticalFlip span:nth-child(2) {
        animation-delay: 2.5s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    }
    .verticalFlip span:nth-child(3) {
        animation-delay: 5s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    }
    .verticalFlip span:nth-child(4) {
        animation-delay: 7.5s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    }
    
    
    /*Vertical Flip Animation*/
    @-moz-keyframes vertical {
        0% { opacity: 0; }
        5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
        10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
        25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
        30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
        80% { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 0;}
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes vertical {
        0% { opacity: 0; }
        5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
        10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
        25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
        30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
        80% { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 0; }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes vertical {
        0% { opacity: 0; }
        5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
        10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
        25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
        30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
        80% { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 0; }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Do you want the 'Teams' to move left and right depending on the length of the characters in the 'verticalFlip'?

Comment: Yes..exactly that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I used a little trick to just use css without javascript.

```css
.sentence {
    text-align: left;
}

.verticalFlip {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 0;
}

.verticalFlip>span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 1rem;
    animation: fakeWidth 10s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: fakeWidth 10s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: fakeWidth 10s linear infinite 0s;
}

.verticalFlip>span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

.verticalFlip>span:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}

.verticalFlip>span:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}

.verticalFlip>div {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-indent: 5px;
}

.verticalFlip>span>span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 40px;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    animation: vertical 10s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: vertical 10s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: vertical 10s linear infinite 0s;
}

.verticalFlip>span:nth-child(2)>span {
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

.verticalFlip>span:nth-child(3)>span {
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}

.verticalFlip>span:nth-child(4)>span {
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}

/*Vertical Flip Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes vertical {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes vertical {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes vertical {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fakeWidth {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }
    5% {
        width: auto;
    }
    25% {
        width: auto;
    }
    30% {
        width: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<text-block class="sentence">For Modern
    <div class="verticalFlip">
        <span>Engineering<span>Engineering</span></span>
        <span>Manufacturing<span>Manufacturing</span></span>
        <span>Quality<span>Quality</span></span>
        <span>Service<span>Service</span></span>
        <div>Teams</div>
    </div>
</text-block>
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much Kim for this..that so nice of you...